# pywinauto: how to get controllers when they don't show using print_control_identifiers and spy tools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

How can I select the menu of this app and write "hello" to the "All Field & Tags"?

This app is tricky, it's somehow embedded in firefox.

```
app=Application().connect(path='zotero.exe')
app.window(title="Zotero",class_name="MozillaWindowClass").print_control_identifiers()
```

Only prints:

```
Control Identifiers:

MozillaWindowClass - 'Zotero'    (L237, T109, R1160, B537)
['ZoteroMozillaWindowClass', 'MozillaWindowClass', 'Zotero']
child_window(title="Zotero", class_name="MozillaWindowClass")
```

So it doesn't find the controls, the menu, and the list of entries (which is hidden behind the spy window).

I tried to use the child_window given above in many ways like

```
app.window(title="Zotero", class_name="MozillaWindowClass").child_window(title="Zotero", class_name="MozillaWindowClass").print_control_identifiers()
```

(title="Zotero", class_name="MozillaWindowClass") but it failed.

Accexplorer (you can get it [here](https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool)) shows a kind of subsection block called `Application` (it's framed in red). I did not find the way to use it either.

You could find this (open source) app [here](http://Zotero-5.0-beta.142+bb0fa73_setup.exe) or from [this page](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/59829/zotero-5-0-beta/p1) (Zotero 5 for windows. It's a 32 bytes app).

[image]

**[EDIT]** Thanks to Vitswd I could print out the control (cf bellow on the right). But I still can't see the controls I'm looking for (the one such as the one needed for the menu, or the field "all field & tags"). There is thousands items in this database app and they are all recognized as control. The python console doesnt handle them. So it only print random part of it (when it does). Is there a way to either exclude some part of the window or to print only the control of some specific parts?

Edit2: I did not find the way to simply .click() on the specific item of the list. I did not find the right syntax to use `pywinauto.findbestmatch.get_control_names(control, allcontrols, textcontrols)` given in the [docs](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findbestmatch.html) but I discovered few things: left click can pause the control. The delay depend of the computer CPU (1mn on a powerful computer).

Using inspect.exe
[image]

Comment: You could try to use Inspect.exe tool in UI Automation mode. If the tool can see the controls of the application you should try to change your pywinauto backend: ```app=Application(backend='uia').connect(path='zotero.exe')```

Comment: @vitswd Thanks! yes I can see the controls on UI mode. I have now the opposite problem: it prints too many controls (after 3 to 5 min!). The app is a database that contains thousand items in the list panel. All of them are recognized as control... The python console only shows me a part of it which weirdly changes from time. So I can't see the control I'm looking for. Is it possible to only print the control of certain part of the window, or to exclude some (like the box called "tree"? (I added a new screenshot in my question)

Comment: I think you have to limit the print depth. Start with the root window: ```app.Zotera.print_control_identifiers(depth=1)```. Find a unique identifier for a control of interest under this window. Repeat the print_control_identifiers with the limited depth for the found control.

Comment: @vitswd thanks! It's weird, `depth=1` *only* prints the single result I got without the `backend='uia'` (cf the result above `MozillaWindowClass...`), so it doesn't actually print any control (I guess it only prints out window specification). And `depth=2` doesn't change anything: it prints the huge amount of control I get using `backend='uia'`.